# How to add/filter markers on gmap v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to add a google map like http://puu.sh/6VgI0.png in which i have 10 locations and each location has 1.title, 2.address, 3.phone number and 4.category(clinic or hospital) and i want to filter the locations with categories like in above screenshot. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step-1: Add markers in the map after getting their respective location points with custom marker icons. Something like below

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
});
```

Step-2: Next you should repeat same for other group of icons.

Step-3: Write a function for both based on the checkboxes selection (which group to be visible or not)

Step-4: In Marker you attach events while click to show popups with all your information.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    // Show popup screen here based on marker parameter.
  });
```

For complete example you can refer this documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events